# find kth smallest number in O(logn) time

Tags: algorithm

Here is the problem, an unsorted array `a[n]`, and I need to find the `kth` smallest number in range `[i, j]`, and absolutely `1<=i<=j<=n, k<=j-i+1`.

Typically I will use `quick-find` to do the job, but it is not fast enough if there many query requests with different range `[i, j]`, I hardly to figure out a algorithm to do the query in `O(logn)` time (**preprocessing is allowed**).

Any idea is appreciated.

**PS**

Let me make the problem easier to understand. Any kinds of preprocessing is allowed, but the query needs to be done in O(logn) time.  And there will be many (more than 1) queries, like find the `1st in range [3,7], or 3rd in range [10,17], or 11th in range [33, 52]`.

By **range [i, j]** I mean in the original array, not sorted or something.

For example, `a[5] = {3,1,7,5,9}`, query `1st in range [3,4]` is `5`, `2nd in range [1,3]` is `5`, `3rd in range [0,2]` is `7`.

Comment: If preprocessing is allowed, sort it.

Comment: @PeterWooster, yes, sort it, then it's easy to find the `kth` in range `[1,n]`, but what the `kth` in range `[i, j]`? Sort elements in `[i,j]` again? NO

Comment: Smells like a variant of the [range minimum query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query) or [lowest common ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) problem.

Comment: @terry-li This is exactly like range minimum query, with the exception that we cannot make the same space optimizations for the preprocessing stage because we need information for the entire sublist if `k` can change from query to query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current solution is O( (logn)^2 ). I am pretty sure it can be modified to run on O(logn). The main advantage of this algorithm over paxdiablo's algorithm is space efficiency. This algorithm needs O(nlogn) space, not O(n^2) space.

First, the complexity of finding kth smallest element from two sorted arrays of length m and n is O(logm + logn). Complexity of finding kth smallest element from arrays of lengths a,b,c,d.. is O(loga+logb+.....).

Now, sort the whole array and store it. Sort the first half and second half of the array and store it and so on. You will have 1 sorted array of length n, 2 sorted of arrays of length n/2, 4 sorted arrays of length n/4 and so on. Total memory required = 1*n+2*n/2+4*n/4+8*n/8...= nlogn.

Once you have i and j figure out the  list of of subarrays which, when concatenated, give you range [i,j]. There are going to be logn number of arrays. Finding kth smallest number among them would take O( (logn)^2) time.

Example for the last paragraph:
Assume the array is of size 8 (indexed from 0 to 7). You have the following sorted lists:

A:0-7, B:0-3, C:4-7, D:0-1, E:2-3, F:4-5, G:6-7.

Now construct a tree with pointers to these arrays such that every node contains its immediate constituents. A will be root, B and C are its children and so on.

Now implement a recursive function that returns a list of arrays.

```
def getArrays(node, i, j):
    if i==node.min and j==node.max:
        return [node];

    if i<=node.left.max:
        if j<=node.left.max:
            return [getArrays(node.left, i, j)];  # (i,j) is located within left node
        else:
            return [ getArrays(node.left, i, node.left.max), getArrays(node.right, node.right.min, j) ]; # (i,j) is spread over left and right node 
    else:
        return [getArrays(node.right, i, j)]; # (i,j) is located within right node
```

Comment: Can you please explain further your last paragraph?

Comment: @user I have added a simple python code. Let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: If I've to sort the array first, then what's wrong with returning just `array[i+k]`?

Comment: @user Consider this example: 5 6 7 1 2 3. The 2nd highest number in [0,2] is 6. If you sot everything, the answer you get will be 2 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

If pre-processing is allowed and not counted towards the time complexity, just use that to construct sub-lists so that you can efficiently find the element you're looking for. As with most optimisations, this trades space for time.

Your pre-processing step is to take your original list of `n` numbers and create a number of *new* sublists.

Each of these sublists is a portion of the original, starting with the `n`th element, extending for `m` elements and *then* sorted. So your original list of:

```
 {3, 1, 7, 5, 9}
```

gives you:

```
 list[0][0] = {3}
 list[0][1] = {1, 3}
 list[0][2] = {1, 3, 7}
 list[0][3] = {1, 3, 5, 7}
 list[0][4] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}

 list[1][0] = {1}
 list[1][1] = {1, 7}
 list[1][2] = {1, 5, 7}
 list[1][3] = {1, 5, 7, 9}

 list[2][0] = {7}
 list[2][1] = {5, 7}
 list[2][2] = {5, 7, 9}

 list[3][0] = {5}
 list[3][1] = {5,9}

 list[4][0] = {9}
```

This isn't a cheap operation (in time *or* space) so you may want to maintain a "dirty" flag on the list so you only perform it the first time after you do an modifying operation (insert, delete, change).

In fact, you can use lazy evaluation for even *more* efficiency. Basically set all sublists to an empty list when you start and whenever you perform a modifying operation. Then, whenever you attempt to access a sublist and it's empty, calculate that sublist (and that one only) before trying to get the `k`th value out of it.

That ensures sublists are evaluated *only* when needed and cached to prevent unnecessary recalculation. For example, if you never ask for a value from the 3-through-6 sublist, it's never calculated.

The pseudo-code for creating all the sublists is basically (`for` loops inclusive at both ends):

```
for n = 0 to a.lastindex:
    create array list[n]
    for m = 0 to a.lastindex - n
        create array list[n][m]
        for i = 0 to m:
            list[n][m][i] = a[n+i]
        sort list[n][m]
```

The code for lazy evaluation is a little more complex (but only a little), so I won't provide pseudo-code for that.

Then, in order to find the `k`th smallest number in the range `i` through `j` (where `i` and `j` are the original indexes), you simply look up `lists[i][j-i][k-1]`, a very fast O(1) operation:

```
                +--------------------------+
                |                          |
                |                          v
1st in range [3,4] (values 5,9),   list[3][4-3=1][1-1-0] = 5
2nd in range [1,3] (values 1,7,5), list[1][3-1=2][2-1=1] = 5
3rd in range [0,2] (values 3,1,7), list[0][2-0=2][3-1=2] = 7
|             |                         ^    ^    ^
|             |                         |    |    |
|             +-------------------------+----+    |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Here's some Python code which shows this in action:

```
orig = [3,1,7,5,9]
print orig

print "====="
list = []
for n in range (len(orig)):
    list.append([])
    for m in range (len(orig) - n):
        list[-1].append([])
        for i in range (m+1):
            list[-1][-1].append(orig[n+i])
        list[-1][-1] = sorted(list[-1][-1])
        print "(%d,%d)=%s"%(n,m,list[-1][-1])

print "====="
# Gives xth smallest in index range y through z inclusive.
x = 1; y = 3; z = 4; print "(%d,%d,%d)=%d"%(x,y,z,list[y][z-y][x-1])
x = 2; y = 1; z = 3; print "(%d,%d,%d)=%d"%(x,y,z,list[y][z-y][x-1])
x = 3; y = 0; z = 2; print "(%d,%d,%d)=%d"%(x,y,z,list[y][z-y][x-1])
print "====="
```

As expected, the output is:

```
[3, 1, 7, 5, 9]
=====
(0,0)=[3]
(0,1)=[1, 3]
(0,2)=[1, 3, 7]
(0,3)=[1, 3, 5, 7]
(0,4)=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
(1,0)=[1]
(1,1)=[1, 7]
(1,2)=[1, 5, 7]
(1,3)=[1, 5, 7, 9]
(2,0)=[7]
(2,1)=[5, 7]
(2,2)=[5, 7, 9]
(3,0)=[5]
(3,1)=[5, 9]
(4,0)=[9]
=====
(1,3,4)=5
(2,1,3)=5
(3,0,2)=7
=====
```

Comment: Sort it, then find `kth` in `[1, n]` with `O(logn)` time, then what it I want to find out the `kth` in `[i, j]` with `1<=i<=j<=n`?

Comment: @Alcott, if `i` is a value, you find that with binary search. Assuming I didn't make that obvious with my original answer, I've updated it to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you understand the problem. I just update my post giving an example

Comment: @Alcott, actually you've now made it much clearer. I've updated my answer based on your edits.

Comment: Upvoted, this is really good idea which makes me recall sparse table, I'll try it out.

Comment: @DaveGalvin, well, I seem to have this problem, `n` is quite big..., so any optimization?

Comment: @Alcott, how big is `n` exactly, and how many times per minute do you need to do it? That will change the value proposition of all proposed solutions.

Comment: `n >= 100000`, `100000` queries needs to be answered.

Comment: If it's 100,000 _different_ subsets (i,j values), very few solutions will be efficient. If there's a lot of identical subsets being queried, lazy evaluation may be good enough since it will amortise towards O(1).

Answer (score 3):

Preprocess: Make an nxn array where the [k][r] element is the kth smallest element of the first r elements (1-indexed for convenience).

Then, given some particular range [i,j] and value for k, do the following:

1. Find the element at the [k][j] slot of the matrix; call this x.
2. go down the i-1 column of your matrix and find how many values in it are smaller than or equal to x (treat column 0 as having 0 smaller entries). By construction, this column will be sorted (all columns will be sorted), so it can be found in log time. Call this value s
3. Find the element in the [k+s][j] slot of the matrix. This is your answer.

### E.g., given 3 1 7 5 9

- 3 1 1 1 1
- X 3 3 3 3
- X X 7 5 5
- X X X 7 7
- X X X X 9

Now, if we're asked for the 2nd smallest in [2,4] range (again, 1-indexing), I first find the 2nd smallest in [1,4] range which is 3. I then look at column 1 and see that there is 1 element less than or equal to 3. Finally, I find the 3rd smallest in [1,4] range at [3][5] slot which is 5, as desired.

This takes n^2 space, and log(n) lookup time.

Comment: Upvote for this idea, but if `n` is big, I can't seem to afford the space.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on either k or the size of the range?

Comment: At step 2, you should check from column `start index - 1`. Your algorithm gives wrong result for 3rd smallest element in [2,4] range.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, for range [1,5] find 5th smallest. Your algorithm gives index out of range error.

Comment: @user There was a typo; you want the number of smaller values before the start of the range, which is column i-1 not k-1 (column 0 in your example which we treat as having no entries).

Comment: See my last comment, your algorithm still wrong after fixing the typo

Comment: @user No, it's right. In your example, i=1, j=5, k=5. In step 1, we find the element at [5][5], which is 9. Next, we look at the i-1 column. In this case it's the 'zeroth' column which we treat has having 0 smaller entries, so s=0. Finally, we find the element in the [5+0][5] = [5][5] slot, which is 9, as it should be.

Comment: @user More generally, We're finding the k'th smallest number of 1-j, and then adjusting it for any smaller numbers outside of i-j, which because of ordering must be in 1-(i-1), and so will appear in column i-1 (or nowhere if we're starting at column 1, in which case we can just pluck the number from [k][j] in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

This one does not require pre-process but is somehow slower than `O(logN)`. It's significantly faster than a naive iterate&count, and could support dynamic modification on the sequence.

It goes like this. Suppose the length `n` has `n=2^x` for some `x`. Construct a *segment-tree* whose root node represent `[0,n-1]`. For each of the node, if it represent a node `[a,b]`, `b>a`, let it has two child nodes each representing `[a,(a+b)/2]`, `[(a+b)/2+1,b]`. (That is, do a recursive divide-by-two).

Then, on each node, maintain a *separate binary search tree* for the numbers within that segment. Therefore, each modification on the sequence takes `O(logN)[on the segement]*O(logN)[on the BST].` Queries can be done like this, Let `Q(a,b,x)` be *rank* of x within segment `[a,b]`. Obviously, if `Q(a,b,x)` can be computed efficiently, a binary search on `x` can compute the answer desired effectively (with an extra `O(logE)` factor.

`Q(a,b,x)` can be computed as: find smallest number of segments that make up `[a,b]`, which can be done in `O(logN)` on the *segment tree*. For each segment, query on the *binary search tree* for that segment for the number of elements less than `x`. Add all these numbers to get `Q(a,b,x)`.

This should be `O(logN*logE*logN)`. Well not exactly what you have asked for though.

Answer (score 0):

In O(log n) time it's not possible to read all of the elements of the array.  Since it's not sorted, and there's no other provided information, this is impossible.

Comment: I said preprocessing is allowed.

Comment: *What kind of preprocessing?* That doesn't mean anything.  Your preprocessing would have to be at least O(n).

Comment: I think it was in the original post actually, he just bolded it in the edit.  Sure okay, preprocess away.  Sort the array, and pick the kth element.  O(1).

Comment: My apologies, @Alcott, I just saw the bold appear and assumed it was added rather than bolded.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way you can do better than O(n) in both worst and average case. You have to look at every single element.